# Variable not defined in pythontex

Tags: pythontex

When I run `pdflatex`, `pythontex`, and `pdflatex`, pythontex raise the error: `NameError: name x is not defined`.

But when I run the py file in Python, it doesn't give an error.

MWE:

```tex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myFile.py}
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Checkbox Demo')

agreement = tk.IntVar()


def print_changed():
    global x
    x = r"\setboolean{mybool}{true}" if agreement.get() else r"\setboolean{mybool}{false}"


ttk.Checkbutton(root,
                text='I agree',
                command=print_changed,
                variable=agreement,
                onvalue=1,
                offvalue=0).pack()


root.mainloop()

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\newboolean{mybool}

\begin{pycode}
import myFile
\end{pycode}
\py{x}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{mybool}}{%
    Print report
}{%
    Do not print report
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure running GUI-related Python code inside LaTeX is a good idea... What are you trying to achieve? Remember that PythonTeX is only for executing some Python code and *typesetting the output* as LaTeX code. How do you expect LaTeX to handle an active Tk interface?

Comment: Also, when the line `\py{x}` is executed by LaTeX (and passed to Python), I see no point where you actually define x. Where is x supposed to receive its initial value?

Comment: This is not a TeX issue, this is a Python issue. The `global x` is not visible outside the module, use `myFile.x`:  → [python - Visibility of global variables in imported modules - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Miyase, I don't expect LaTeX to handle Tk interface. Python executes the code (Tk) and generates necessary global variables and LaTeX uses it. Also, the x will defined after finishing Tk interface by Python.